# How To Get Filename In Google Service Drive?

Tags: php, wordpress, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I try to fetch my google drive folder image use in Google_Service_Drive ..i Cannot Understand it's not execute image name fetch it's code is fine.i'think but why it's not fetch any image..

There is a problem with my code, I need to find it..and how can I do this?

```
Folder structure -

        $folder => image1
                   image2
                   image3
                   image4

image folder link : xxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxrt;
```

Now I get Main folder list and id and name using below code

```
file name: class-image.php

function testtt(){
$version        = '3.7.3';
    $plugin_name    = 'wpgsi';

    $common         = new Wpgsi_common($plugin_name, $version);             
    $wpgsi_events   = new Wpgsi_Events($plugin_name, $version, $common);
    $googleSheet    = new Wpgsi_Google_Sheet($plugin_name, $version, $common); 

    $Wpgsi_Images   = new Wpgsi_Images($plugin_name, $version, $wpgsi_events, $googleSheet);
    $client         = $Wpgsi_Images->getClient();
    $service        = new Google_Service_Drive( $client );

    $sub_folders = array(
                            '...........................rt'
                        );
    $folders_query = implode("' or parents in '", $sub_folders );
    echo $q."<br>";
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($folders_query);
    echo "</pre>";

    $imagename = "xxxxxxxxxxx_WB_R01.png";  
    $imgname = preg_replace( '/[^a-z0-9.-_]/i', ' ', $imagename );
    $q       = "name contains '". $imgname ."' and trashed = false and (parents in '". $folders_query ."')";

    echo $q;
    $request = $service->files->listFiles( [
        'q'  => $q,
    ]);
    echo $q."<br>";
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($request);
    echo "</pre>";
}
add_action('init','testtt');
```

now i got this output -

```
name contains 'xxxxxxxxxxx_WB_R01.png' and trashed = false and (parents in 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxrt')name contains 'xxxxxxxxxxx_WB_R01.png' and trashed = false and (parents in 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxrt')
    Google_Service_Drive_FileList Object

(
    [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
        (
        )
[modelData:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[processed:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[collection_key:protected] => files
[filesType:protected] => Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile
[filesDataType:protected] => array
[incompleteSearch] => 
[kind] => drive#fileList
[nextPageToken] => 
[files] => Array
    (
    )
)
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. From your title `How To Get Filename In Google Service Drive?`, I understood that you want to retrieve the filename from Google Drive. But, when I saw your showing script, it seemed that you had already used the filename. So, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output values you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: @Tanaike First of Thankyou for your answer. i edit my code please check.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. What are your expected input and output values? From `How To Get Filename In Google Service Drive?`, I understand that you want to retrieve the filename from Google Drive. If my understanding is correct, what is your expected input value?

Comment: i would start by checking your regex.   then why not just search on the file mime type?

Comment: @Tanaike The logic is that if the link to a Google Drive file contains images they will appear in the [files] of the response. It is not working properly..when the Google Drive link or it is all correct. So what's the problem?

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo How can I take help from there? Can you please explain to some briefly?